# Custom toggle in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, toggle

I have 3 `Buttons` that need to be toggles i.e.. when I click on one, if any of the other are selected they will be deselected so only one `Button` can be selected at any one time .

Basically update an integer with that particular button selected. I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Check out UISegmentedControl [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that batter approach is `segmentedControl` but if you want this with button then you can create one more instance of `UIButton` like this and then use it like this way.

```
var selectedButton: UIButton = UIButton()
```

Now if you have common method for all 3 button you can try like this

```
@IBOutlet func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedButton.selected = false
    self.selectedButton = sender
    self.selectedButton.selected = true        
}
```

If you have 3 different `IBAction` then create one function like this and call that function from all 3 `Button` action.

```
func setSelectedButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedButton.selected = false
    self.selectedButton = sender
    self.selectedButton.selected = true        
}
```

Now call this function from all 3 action method like this way.

```
self.setSelectedButton(sender)
```

Comment: one more question how would i give values to the buttons then set a default state im currently using 3 IBAction buttons calling the self.setSelectedButton(sender) on each button but when the device starts i dont have a default button state

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`  write this two line `self.selectedButton = defaultButton    self.selectedButton.selected = true `

Comment: i get a Use of unresolved identifier 'defaultButton' ive tried assigning buttonOne to defaultButton but still wont work

Comment: `defultbutton` means, you need to use there Button object that you want default selected from 3 buttons.

Comment: yeah i know what default means what im saying is when i add self.SelectedButton = defaultButton and self.SelectedButton.Selected = true to the viewDidLoad() method i get the Use of unresolved identifier 'defaultButton'  fault

Comment: You don't understanding what i am saying, Have you declare 3 Outlet of that buttons?

Comment: Yeah I've declared 3 Outlets

Comment: Then you need to use one of that variable name for defaule select, on place of defaultButton.